# How can the Fibonacci numbers be extended to a Fibonacci number triangle?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, fibonacci-numbers

A way to study a sequence is to apply a transformation to the
sequence. The transformations we want to consider are transformations
from 1-dim sequences to 2-dim sequences. We assume 1-dim sequences
defined for $n \ge 0$ and the image of the transformation an integer
triangle in the range $0 \le k \le n$.

The question is: *"What are interesting 2-dim images of the
Fibonacci numbers which can be constructed this way?"*

In the rest of this post, we will give three examples for this
approach, which all have been studied (see the OEIS references)
and can be generated by a single method: a transformation which
we will call the Riordan Square of a sequence. Basically, this
transformation is the self convolution of the sequence.

Recently [Somos](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4034516)
showed on MSE how the Fibonacci numbers can be
studied by looking at various variants of the definition of
the generating function. We will take up this setup but add
another parameter, c, denoting an additive constant.

$$ gf(a, b, c) = \frac{a\!+\!(b\!-\!a)x}{1-x-x^2} + c. $$

#### Fibonacci-Triangle [A063967](https://oeis.org/A063967).

```
           1;
         1,  1;
       2,  3,  1;
     3,  7,  5, 1;
   5,  15, 16, 7, 1;
 8,  30,  43, 29, 9, 1;
  
gf(1, 1, 0): RiordanSquare(1/(1 - x - x^2)).
```

Row sums are [A002605](https://oeis.org/A002605) (a transform of the Jacobsthal sequence).

#### Fibonacci-Triangle [A155161](https://oeis.org/A155161), with leading '1' deleted.

```
           0;
         1,  0;
       1,  1,  0;
     2,   2,  1, 0;
   3,   5,  3,  1, 0;
 5,   10, 9,  4,  1, 0;

gf(0, 1, 0): RiordanSquare(x/(1 - x - x^2)).
```

Row sums are [A000129](https://oeis.org/A000129) (Pell numbers).

#### Fibonacci-Triangle [A193737](https://oeis.org/A193737).

```
           1;
         1,  1;
       1,  2,  1;
     2,  4,  3,  1;
   3,  8,  8,  4,  1;
 5, 15, 19, 13,  5,  1; 

gf(0, 1, 1), RiordanSquare(x/(1 - x - x^2) + 1).
```

Row sums are [A052542](https://oeis.org/A052542) (twice the Pell numbers).

We see that even the most straightforward evaluations of these triangles
(here the row sums) lead to other interesting sequences.
And that the choice of the start determines
the ability to invert: the choice '1' leads to [A091698](https://oeis.org/A091698)
whereas the choice '0' produces a singular matrix.

Certainly, there are many other interesting integer triangles based
on the Fibonacci numbers. Please show us some.

---

Appendix: The recursive computation of the Riordan square is
sketched by this pseudo code:

```
RiordanSquare(gf) = 
    T[n, 0] = [x^n] gf; 
    T[n, k] = Sum[T[j, k - 1]*T[n - j, 0], {j, k - 1, n - 1}]; 
    Return Table[ T[n, k], {n, 0, length - 1}, {k, 0, n}].
```

More about the Riordan Square transformation can be found on my
[blog](http://luschny.de/math/seq/RiordanSquare.html).

Comment: Fibonomials (Priceless !) https://oeis.org/A010048 ... I also love this one ... https://oeis.org/A028412